# whether I would use "of" or not in this sentence

Tags: grammar

sample : The efforts of discovering new sea routes resulted in the creation (of) new maps, as well

I feel like I need to put "of" in between "creation" and "new maps".
But does it also a proper usage, if I remove "of" in between the words in the sentence?

like "in the creation new maps"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely need "of" in this sentence. *Creation new maps* by itself does not make sense. The "of" tells you what was created.